# How to Receive the one stepper state value in to the another stepper in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a stepper as a functional component as below

```
import NewProfile from './NewProfile';

function getSteps() {
  return ['Carete Profile', 'Contact'];
}


function getStepContent(step) {
  switch (step) {
    case 0:
      return <NewProfile  type={valueTobePass}></NewProfile>;
    default:
      return <contact></contact>;
  }
}

  export default function HorizontalLinearStepper(props,previousState) 
  {
  
   const classes = useStyles();
   const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
  const [publisherId, setPublisherId] = React.useState(0);
  const [skipped, setSkipped] = React.useState(new Set());
  const steps = getSteps();
  const isStepOptional = (step) => {
    return (step === 1 ||
    step === 2)
  };
console.log(props.newUserId);
  const isStepSkipped = (step) => {
    return skipped.has(step);
  };
  const addPublisherid =(publisherId) => {
    setPublisherId(publisherId);
    console.log(publisherId)
  }
  const handleNext = () => {
    let newSkipped = skipped;
    if (isStepSkipped(activeStep)) {
      newSkipped = new Set(newSkipped.values());
      newSkipped.delete(activeStep);
    }
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
    setSkipped(newSkipped);
  };
  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1);
  };
 

    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
    setSkipped((prevSkipped) => {
      const newSkipped = new Set(prevSkipped.values());
      newSkipped.add(activeStep);
      return newSkipped;
    });
  }
 
 return (

    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Stepper activeStep={activeStep}>
        {steps.map((label, index) => {
          const stepProps = {};
          const labelProps = {};
          if (isStepOptional(index)) {
            labelProps.optional = <Typography variant="caption">Optional</Typography>;
          }
          if (isStepSkipped(index)) {
            stepProps.completed = false;
          }
          return (
            <Step key={index} {...stepProps}>
              <StepLabel {...labelProps}>{label}</StepLabel>
            </Step>
          );
        })}
        {props.step}
      </Stepper>
      <div>
        {activeStep === steps.length ? (
          <div>
            <Typography className={classes.instructions}>
              All steps completed - you&apos;re finished
            </Typography>
            
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <Typography className={classes.instructions}>{getStepContent(activeStep,previousState,props.type)}</Typography>
            <div>
              <Button disabled={activeStep === 0} onClick={handleBack} className={classes.button}>
                Back
              </Button>
              {isStepOptional(activeStep) && (
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  color="primary"
                  onClick={handleSkip}
                  className={classes.button}
                >
                  Skip
                </Button>
              )}

              <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                onClick={handleNext}
                className={classes.button}
              >
                {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? 'Finish' : 'Next'}
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and the step is class component

```
class NewProfile extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Name: '',
            newUserId:'',
        }
      
    }
    editAccountDetails = () => {
        axios.post(`url`, {
            "Name": this.state.Name,
        })
            .then(response => response.data)
            .then((data) => {
                this.setState({newUserId:data.id})
            }).catch(error => { console.log(error); })

    }

  
    render() {
        return <div>  
                                    <TextField }}
                                        onChange={(event) => {
                                            this.setState({ "Name": 
                                        event.target.value })
                                        }} />
                                  
                                      <Button onClick={this.editAccountDetails} >
                                            Submit  </MButton> 
                                    </div>
        </div>
    }
}


const NewProfileHOC = withStyles(styles)(NewProfile);
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NewProfileHOC);
```

I want to retrieve the 'state' of the 'NewProfile' Component(Class Component) in the Stepper Component (Functional Component) for my further process

i tried with callBack function and context it is not working please help me out with this

thank you in advance

Comment: Can you pass it as a prop to the Stepper?